How to see all Tifftools library python tags
I am using Python tifftools library to modify and create DNG format image (tiff). I want to set all tiff tags individually. I am using tifftools.tiff_set function. It takes an argument setlist, which is a list of tuples, first element of the tuple is tag identifier (e.g. tifftools.Tag.XRESOLUTION, tifftools.Tag.CFAPATTERN...) and the second is actual value. How to obtain a list of possible tags identifiers without just guessing?
Or what is the alternative to this approach? Maybe different library?

for tag in tifftools.Tag: print(tag)

this was helpful!

You can find a complete list of TIFF tags in Tags for TIFF, DNG, and Related Specifications.I think tifftools follow that specification but if you want to know exactly what constants it accept you could see its code, specifically constants.py .
